# Is a function just a type like any other type?

Tags: function, go, types

The following compilation error makes sense to me

```
type A int

var bar int
var foo A
bar = 2
foo = bar // cannot use bar (variable of type int) as type A in assignment
```

, however the following lack of compilation error surprises me

```
type A func()

var bar func()
var foo A
bar = func() {}
foo = bar
```

Similarly, here is an example to define and use a type

```
type A struct{x int}

bar := A{x: 3}
```

In the same logic I was hoping to define and use a func type with

```
type A func(a int) string

bar := A{
    fmt.Println(a)
    return "Hello"
}
```

but it does not work. One must do

```
type A func(a int) string

bar := func(a int) string {
    fmt.Println(a)
    return "Hello"
}
```

It feels to me that a `func` type is a special kind of type. Is it? Wouldn't iot be more correct/intuitive if golang had a `type` and a `typefunc` keywords, such that

```
type A func()      // would throw a compilation error: a func is not a type
typefunc A func()  // would work fine
```

Comment: *the following lack of compilation error surprises me [...]* See https://go.dev/ref/spec#Assignability. The compiler allows you to assign `bar` to `foo` because `A` and `func ()` have identical underlying types (`func ()`) and one of them is not a named type.

Comment: *I was hoping to define and use a func type [...]* Where would the parameter name (`a`) come from?

Comment: @jub0bs For your second comment. As the parameter is made explicit in the type definition, I would have hoped it was not necessary to specify it again when defining the function. `type A func(a int) string`, `bar := A{...}` and `myString := bar(myInt)`.

Comment: That could work, but I think that would be too much magic for Gophers :)